# vb.net 2013 - removing blank lines with streamreader

Tags: arrays, vb.net, streamreader, blank-line

I am using this code snippet (found on here) to read a csv file into an array.

```
sFile = "c:\test.txt"
Dim sData() As String
Dim arrName, arrValue as New List(Of String)()

Using sr As New StreamReader(sFile)
    While Not sr.EndOfStream
        sData = sr.ReadLine().Split(","c)

        arrName.Add(sData(0).Trim())
        arrValue.Add(sData(1).Trim())
    End While
End Using
```

My source file contains 2 - 3 blank lines at the end of the file.
Despite using Trim() - I am still getting these blank lines inserted into the array, and this is causing the rest of my code to fail.

I have verified that it works by deleting the blank lines.

I have tried various techniques found on here and on MSDN but I just can't seem to get rid of these blank lines.

Can anyone help please?

Thanks.

Comment: check if `sData(0)` or `sData(1)` `IsNullOrEmpty`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read the line into a separate variable and check if that is empty before parsing the data:

```
Using sr As New StreamReader(sFile)
    While Not sr.EndOfStream
        Dim sLine As String = sr.ReadLine()
        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sLine) Then
            sData = sLine.Split(","c)

            arrName.Add(sData(0).Trim())
            arrValue.Add(sData(1).Trim())
        End If
    End While
End Using
```

You may also want to add further validity checks (e.g. if there is no comma, `sData(1)` will throw an exception, and what if there are multiple commas?).

Answer (score 2):

I'd skip the streamreader and use `File.ReadLines()` method. This returns an enumerable that can work with the `Where()` function:

```
For Each line As String in File.ReadLines(sFile).Where(Function(l) Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l))
    Dim data = line.Split(","c)
    arrName.Add(data(0).Trim())
    arrValue.Add(data(1).Trim())
Next line
```

Additionally, paired arrays/Lists such as `arrName` and `arrValue` are an anti-pattern. Much better to use a small class:

```
Public Class MyData
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Value As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal line As String)
       Dim data() as String = line.Split(","c)
       Name = data(0).Trim()
       Value = data(1).Trim()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now you can have a single list like this:

```
Dim data As List(Of MyData)
```

And you can write the rest of the code in a single line:

```
data = File.ReadLines(sFile).Where(Function(l) Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l)).Select(Function(s) New MyData(l)).ToList()
```

But for readability:

```
Dim data As List(Of MyData) = File.ReadLines(sFile).
         Where(Function(l) Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l)).
         Select(Function(s) New MyData(s)).
         ToList()
```

Comment: Thanks for a comprehensive answer, however I couldn't get this to work. I can't remember what the error was (!) but IIRC it was related to string errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
sr.ToString().TrimEnd( Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray())
```

or

```
'vbCrLf or vbNewLine (might work as well)
```

Comment: I replaced "While Not sr.EndOfStream" with your first example and I get the following error: Conversion from string "System.IO.StreamReader" to type 'Long' is not valid.